# override spring batch admin to use mysql database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to use mysql database instead of default HSQL in spring batch admin. For that as per documentation

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/reference.xhtml   and  [Using jndi datasource with spring batch admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062922/using-jndi-datasource-with-spring-batch-admin)

I copied `env-context.xml` to `src/main/resources/META-INF/batch/override/manager/env-context.xml`  and changed its configuration value from

```
<value>classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT:hsql}.properties</value>
```

to

```
 <value>classpath:batch-mysql.properties</value>
```

Below is my full configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!--  Use this to set additional properties on beans at run time -->
    <bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/bootstrap/batch.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:batch-default.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:batch-mysql.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I also tried coping data-source-context.xml to same folder and changing its configurations to mysql

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/batch" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!--  Initialise the database if enabled: -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="false" ignore-failures="DROPS">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:/business-schema-mysql.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

But it still using hsql database? How to override default configuration to use mysql database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't replace the `<value>classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT:hsql}.properties</value>`.  Instead, pass in an environment variable `ENVIRONMENT` set to mysql.  That should cause all the appropriate components to pick up the correct database.  You can read more about that feature here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/infrastructure.html#Environment_Settings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try using just annotations without any xml configurations - try this

```
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
```

It is working. My code is available here - http://github.com/sidnan/spring-batch-example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the connection working with above approach with below steps

First, I copied `env-context.xml` to `src/main/resources/META-INF/batch/override/manager/env-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">`

    <!--  Use this to set additional properties on beans at run time -->
    <bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/bootstrap/batch.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:batch-default.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT:sqlserver}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

After that, put the following entries in `batch-sqlserver.properties` of sql server under resources as

```
# Default placeholders for database platform independent features 
batch.remote.base.url=http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample
# Non-platform dependent settings that you might like to change

batch.jdbc.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=batchrepo
batch.jdbc.user=la
batch.jdbc.password=la
atch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=true
batch.data.source.init=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=

batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer
batch.lob.handler.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler
batch.database.incrementer.parent=columnIncrementerParent
batch.grid.size=2
batch.jdbc.pool.size=6
batch.verify.cursor.position=true
batch.isolationlevel=ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
batch.initializer.enabled=false
```

Since my tables were already created in the database, I skipped these entries:
    #batch.drop.script=/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-sqlserver.sql
    #batch.schema.script=/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sqlserver.sql
    #batch.business.schema.script=business-schema-sqlserver.sql

Finally, with `batch.initializer.enabled=false`, I was finally able to make the connection.

I can monitor the job as well as lunch the new jobs in my admin application.  These launched jobs also appear in the DB.